# vlookup to pick the nearest date lesser date from the reference cell

Tags: vba, vlookup

I required your support,

I have a datasheet (Sheet1) which is having product details and its dates which are been imported. Another sheet (Sheet2) which are also having product details and its dates which are been exported by the seller. Both the sheet dates might not be equal nor the total no. of rows will be the same.

I wanted to understand if a Vlookup can compare the dates of sheet 1 & sheet2 for each product keeping the imported dates of sheet 1 as a reference and pull the nearest lowest date from the sheet2 "created date"

Sheet 1 is having the data which is from imported data

Sheet 2 is the date which shows the actual export from the seller

So now I need to do a comparison for the Product bearing (cell A2) from Sheet 1, which is having the imported date as of 10/22/2019. Comparing to the next Sheet2 (Image 2 ) for the same product bearing which is having the created dates as 10/18/2019, 11/08/2019,10/16/2019.

The formula should now pick a date which is nearest lesser to the imported date which is in the sheet1. in this case, formula to pick the date 10/18/2019.

[image: Image 1 - Imported data with dates[][1]]

[image: Image2 - Exported Data from Seller]

I tried to sort the data to lowest to highest and highest to lowest, but v-lookup results were not always right. I tried to insert the IF condition resulted in no luck.

It would be very helpful if you all share some insight into this case.

Thank you for reading the above case.

Answer (score 1):

Use AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,7,B2:B100/((A2:A100="Bearing")*(B2:B100<=Date(2019,10,22)),1)
```

Comment: Hello Scott, Thanks for reading the above case and sharing your ideas. i will try the above and let you soon. thanks for the support